# C# Drawin on Images twice

Tags: c#, drawing

I have an image and I aim to draw on it twice: once for detecting the aphids and another one for detecting the non-aphids. I am not quite sure on how to do this yet and am open to suggestions. Am I doing it right?

Thanks for helping!

```
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
BlobCounter blobCounter2 = new BlobCounter();

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
Graphics h = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);

//filtering the blobs before searching for blobs 
blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
blobCounter.MinHeight = newImage.Height / 200;
blobCounter.MaxHeight = newImage.Height / 24;
blobCounter.MinWidth = newImage.Width / 200;
blobCounter.MaxWidth = newImage.Width / 24;

blobCounter2.FilterBlobs = true;
blobCounter2.MinHeight = newImage.Height / 100;
blobCounter2.MaxHeight = newImage.Height / 10;
blobCounter2.MinWidth = newImage.Width / 100;
blobCounter2.MaxWidth = newImage.Width / 20;

//arranges the blobs by Size
blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Size;

blobCounter2.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Size;

blobCounter.ProcessImage(newImage);

blobCounter2.ProcessImage(newImage);
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

Blob[] blobs2 = blobCounter2.GetObjectsInformation();
foreach (Blob b in blobs)
{
    //getting the found blob edgepoints 
    List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(b);

    List<IntPoint> edgePoints2 = blobCounter2.GetBlobsEdgePoints(b);

    //if you want to mark every edge point RED 
    foreach (IntPoint point in edgePoints)
        newImage.SetPixel(point.X, point.Y, Color.Orange);
    //if you want to draw a rectangle around the blob 
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, b.Rectangle);

    foreach (IntPoint point in edgePoints2)
        newImage.SetPixel(point.X, point.Y, Color.Blue);
    h.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, b.Rectangle);
    //new
   // int count = Blob.Length;
   // MessageBox.Show("Total objects found: " + count);
    //endnew
    pictureBox4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox4.Image = newImage;
}
MessageBox.Show("Number of segmented blobs found:" + blobCounter.ObjectsCount.ToString()+ ".");
g.Dispose();
h.Dispose();
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? Also why create two Graphics objects for the same image?

Comment: You are doing nothing with `blobs2` ?

Comment: @FirstStep My problem is that only the drawings from g.DrawRectangle can be seen.

Comment: Do not use two Graphics objects that both point into the same Bitmap! Use one for all the drawing! But since you don't change the Rectangle `b` only the last drawing can be visible anyway